# How do I remove bookmarked repositories from my GitHub's home list?

Tags: github

When I open my homepage in GitHub I see a useful list of all the repositories I'm a collaborator of, but I also see two other repositories marked with the icon of a bookmark.

I had cloned them a while ago for some tests, and I've personally no clue why they show up on this list.

Does anyone know how to remove them? I tried anything that came to my mind already.

[image]